# Error while creating external hive table using cassandra storage handler

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hive, bigdata, hiveql

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
message (key string, loc string, machineid string, message string, msgdate string, quantity int, time string)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraStorageHandler'WITH SERDEPROPERTIES
 ("cassandra.columns.mapping" = ":key,smslog,:location,:machineid,:message,:msgdate,:quantity,:time", "cassandra.cf.name" = "smslog", 
"cassandra.host" = "127.0.0.1" , "cassandra.port" = "9160",
"cassandra.partitioner" = "org.apache.cassandra.dht.
RandomPartitioner" )
TBLPROPERTIES ("cassandra.ks.name" = "SMSLogs");
```

> Failed with exception org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error in loading storage handler.org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraStorageHandler
>   FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask